# setting up domain name locally on raspbian stretch

Tags: nginx, dns, raspbian

Instead of registering a domain name just to put it on the server_name in the site configuration of Nginx how can we locally setup a domain name and to then create a CNAME DNS entry to refer to the nginx server DNS name locally. When you spin up a replacement server, update the CNAME to point to the new servers DNS name.

I am running web server nginx on raspbian stretch.

Comment: Can't you change in /etc/hosts the DNS to the IP you want (in my understanding I think you can do it)? Or you want to do it with nginx?

Comment: Well for any new computer or somewone connecting from mobile device over WiFi will try to open the web app of which we set DNS in /etc/hosts file will not work.